# Permitir HTML em comentários no WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo uma espécie de plataforma de orçamentos no WordPress e estou utilizando o próprio sistema de posts e comentários para tal, com apenas algumas modificações. Uma delas é a substituição do textarea do form de comentário, por uma tabela com alguns inputs, pois servirá melhor para esse sistema:
[image: Tabela onde preenchemos os dados do comment/orçamento]

Aí quando a pessoa envia essa comentário, eu injeto no value do input que envia essas informações o HTML de uma tabela com os dados dessa tabela. O problema que estou tendo é que o conteúdo desse comentário é armazenado no Banco de Dados sem o HTML, salvando apenas o conteúdo de cada Tag. O mesmo não acontece quando um Administrador é quem faz o comentário:

Como o comentário de um administrador aparece no frontend:
[image: Comentário de um ADM]

Como o comentário de um usuário com outra função aparece:
[image: Comentário de usuário com outra função]

Sou bem iniciante em PHP, então provavelmente isso é apenas uma configuração bem fácil de mudar, porém não tenho ideia de como proceder.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema: usuários sem a permissão unfiltered_html não podem inserir algumas tags em postagens ou comentário e ela só vem habilitada para os adms, por isso não funcionava para os outros usuários. Para resolver, eu encontrei um plugin que permite habilitar diversas permissões para cada função no site, mais detalhes do plugin e dessa permissão no [post](https://publishpress.com/blog/unfiltered-html-permission-wordpress/?unapproved=47123&moderation-hash=3fd676844dc4a666dbf8e531c122d86a#comment-47123)